# Execute function after `.load` finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to load the file (using the href variable) AFTER the slideUp function, and not before.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content").show().load($(".link2:first").attr('href'));

    $(".link").click(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#content").slideUp("slow");
        $("#content").slideDown("slow").load(href);

        return false;
    });
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<a href="testar2.html" class="link">Link 1</a>
<a href="testar.html" class="link">Link 2</a>
<div id="content">-</div>
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/load/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
$("#content").slideUp("slow", function(){
    $(this).load(href, function (responseText, status, req) {
        if (status != "error") $(this).slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

I also added an error check just in case `.load()` fails.

Comment: Yes, I think this is what the OP wants, though the question is somewhat oblique.

Answer (score 1):

Use the callback to your advantage

```
$("#content").load(href, function() { 
    $(this).stop().slideDown("slow"); 
});
```

You can wrap the load the same way by putting it in the slideUp callback. Personally I would not wait for the animation to be done and do it like I did above because that is more time the  user has to wait for content. The stop will kill the up animation.